# How to fix error in substring due to spaces

Tags: java, substring

I am trying to take specific values from a file to write to the database through Java. I have used the `substring()` function to store values. In one column, I have some empty fields and some with data. When it encounters an empty field, it gives me an error. How to fix this?

```
String st = strline.substring(453,457);
```

I am getting this error in output due to the above code:

```
Error: begin 453, end 457, length 452
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's logging that error? If it's an exception, could you include the type and stack trace, rather than just the message? My guess is that the problem is that `strline` is only 452 characters long...

Comment: Provide some more information, like `strline` etc.

Comment: Check if `strline.length() >= 457` before calling `substring()`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It is not clear from your question what you are asking. Be sure and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question so we can help you with a good answer.

Comment: are your fields comma separated or something? you might be better off using `String.split()` than `String.substring()`. Can you provide examples of the Strings you are parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Like Eritrean suggested you should check the length of the string before calling the substring method.

`String st = strline.length() > 452 ? strline.substring(453,457) : "";`

Comment: While this will stop an error for this particular scenario, it could introduce other problems. There's not enough information here to answer.